# Using the NMF method for hashtag recommendation in collaborative filter recommendation systems

Tags: python, collaborative-filtering, nmf

I want to use the NMF method to recommend hashtags in a collaborative filtering, I have written the following code and created the NMF matrix from the (user-hashtag) matrix. But for the next part that should be recommended, I don't know what to do! In fact, I have to recommend the top 5 hashtags. please help me.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
model = NMF(n_components=2, init='random', random_state=0)
W = model.fit_transform(matrix)
H = model.components_

NMF_matrix = np.dot(W,H)
print(NMF_matrix)

#collaborative filtering
vectorA =  vector_x_testval_username[i]
hashtag_recommend_collaborative = []
vectorA.sort()
vectorA = list(vectorA)
vectorA.reverse()
A = vectorA[0:5]
for k in A:
    for j in range(len(new_hashtags)):
        if( k == vector_x_testval_username[i][j] ):
            hashtag_recommend_collaborative.append(new_hashtags[j])
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.